# Whoops, looks like we hit a network issue. Let's try that again? [99]

Tags: ios, swift3, twitter-digits, xcode8.2, fabric-digits

I used these code for sms verification using fabric digits in xcode 8.2.1 in swift3.

```
let authButton = DGTAuthenticateButton(authenticationCompletion: { (session, error) in
            if (session != nil) {
                let message = "Phone number: \(session!.phoneNumber)"
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "You are logged in!", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: .none))
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: .none)
            } else {
                NSLog("Authentication error: %@", error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        authButton?.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(authButton!)
```

I got an error message when I click "send confirmation code", After I entered phone number. How can I solve this problem? [image: Error message]

Comment: Did you try to setup `Digits` before `Twitter`?

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://docs.fabric.io/apple/digits/advanced-setup.html#verifying-a-user , You need to add :

Digits.sharedInstance().start(withConsumerKey: "Your API Key", consumerSecret: "Your Secret Key")

before

Fabric.with([Digits.self])

in your AppDelegate.swift file

This has solved my problem